# Different Names on Passports

Tags: passports

I have different surnames on my passports.
I'd like to use the one passport to leave my current country and enter the new country with the other passport.
Due to some laws conflicting in both countries, I had to change my surname to that of my mothers on my one passport, but the other passport still has my other surname on it which is on my birth certificate, etc.
I'd just like to know if it were possible to use both passports (leave the one country with the one passport and enter the other country with the other passport)
Would I run into some problems because of this?

Comment: This is not answerable without specifying the two or four countries (origin A, arrival B, nationality C, nationality D) involved. Every country may have their own requirements and procedures concerning exit, entry, passenger information and sharing of other information.

Comment: For a general overview: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/52100/i-have-two-passports-nationalities-how-do-i-use-them-when-i-travel

Comment: Having different names in different passports for the same person may be a problem. This goes beyond the question of how to travel with multiple passports, and depends on how each of these countries defines what your "legal" name is. Generally you can get in trouble with law enforcement because it may seem like a case of forgery or identity theft.

Comment: The country I'm travelling from is Germany and the country I'm trying to enter would be Namibia, Africa. I would like to leave Germany with my german passport and enter Namibia with my namibian passport. But as mentioned before they have different surnames on them, because of a conflicting law whereas I had to change my surname to that of my mothers on only my german passport